# Mathematica takes a long time and aborts

Tags: equation-solving

I am using mathematica to solve the following system of equations (consisting of 90 equations):

https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/34100283-a4fa-4d0c-ab4f-d2fbdcb1e843

Mathematica refuses to solve for it as it takes too much time. Are there any strategies/solutions for tackling this problem?

Thank you

Comment: I should highlight that I only care about the number of solution sets.

Comment: Solving equations can be very difficult in general. Without knowing a lot about the **actual** problem you are trying to solve, it is impossible to give good advice.